# Disabling focus in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, android-listview

In an Android application I have a ListActivity. After creating it I have a broadcast receiver which has to disable some items in the list. So I have a pice of code ike this one:

```
View child = getListView().getChildAt(i);
child.setEnabled(false);
```

It works in the way it changes the color of the disabled views to gray. But I need to avoid this items can be clicked. So I've tried to call

```
child.setFocusable(false);
```

or

```
child.setClickable(false);
```

but in both cases onListItemClick is called after pressing on a disabled option.

How can I avoid that onListItemClick method is called when these textviews are clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the views does nothing with regard to the `onListItemClick` event.

The child must be disabled by the Adapter you are using to populate the list.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)

This method needs to be overriden to return false for each item you do not want to be clickable.  You should also add a method to your adapter like `setEnabled(int position, boolean enabled)`